# Rendering 10x10 cubes openGl 1.0 es

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

Can someone tels me what's wrong here ;)
i render cubes of dimension 2x2 and resoult is :

[image: Thats wrong]

```
gl.glPopMatrix();

    for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
    gl.glTranslatef(-10, 0, 0f);
    cube.draw(gl);
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
    gl.glTranslatef(2.0f, 0, 0f);
    cube.draw(gl);
    }
    gl.glTranslatef(-8f, 0, -2);
    }
```

Comment: Look's like there's no depth testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable depth testing:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

And don't forget to clear both color and depth buffer:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```